# How to add a custom empty cart button on configurable product page:Magento

Tags: php, magento, cart

I have a configurable product with two option and i want to add an empty cart button on that page to empty the items:

i have copied the button from cart page and embed it but its not worked.
please suggest a way to add a button.

```
 <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Empty Cart'); ?>" class="button2 btn-empty" id="empty_cart_button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Empty Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new controller and then add the action of the controller to the button you just created.

Then create a model to empty the `$quote` which is the current items. Thats the basic theory.

Inchoo created something similar to what you want check it out [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/theres-no-empty-cart-on-magentos-cart-page/).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `updatePostAction` function of `Mage_Checkout_CartController`, you should indeed be able to do that the way you want it. But right now your button is not linked to a form, so it does nothing.

But you will also need a valid form key for that to work.

Extract of `Mage_Checkout_CartController` :

```
public function updatePostAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    $updateAction = (string)$this->getRequest()->getParam('update_cart_action');

    switch ($updateAction) {
        case 'empty_cart':
            $this->_emptyShoppingCart();
            break;
        case 'update_qty':
            $this->_updateShoppingCart();
            break;
        default:
            $this->_updateShoppingCart();
    }

    $this->_goBack();
}
```

So this should be something working :

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Empty Cart'); ?>" class="button2 btn-empty" id="empty_cart_button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Empty Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
</form>
```